# Menu con Menu dropdown no hace link en el link padre Bootstrap

Tags: html5, bootstrap, bootstrap-4, dropdownlist

poseo el siguiente codigo

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a title="Ver Mensualidades" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="mensualidades.php" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="fa fa-money-bill-alt fa-fw"></i>  Mensualidades <span data-toggle="popover" title="Mensualidad Detectada" data-content="Se ha detectado un pago de Mensualidad, pendiente de conformacion." class="badge badge-light"><?php suma_mensualidad(); 
         echo $pendiente_mensualidad; ?></span>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a title="Mensualidades por Aprobar" class="dropdown-item" href="mensualidades.php"><i class="fa fa-money-check fa-fw"></i> Mensualidades por Aprobar</a>
          <a title="Ver Todas las Mensulidades" class="dropdown-item" href="todas_mensualidades.php"><i class="fa fa-list-alt fa-fw"></i> Ver todas las Mensualidades</a>
        </div>
      </li>
```

Me gustaria que al dar click en el link padre MENSUALIDADES me lleve a la web mensualidades.php y de esta manera lo pueda borrar del desplegable que poseo, quedando solo el link VER TODAS LAS MENSUALIDADES que me llevaria a la web: todas_mensualidades.php.

Estoy trabajando con Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Solo quieres que cuando le des click al padre te redireccione pero manteniendo el estilo del dropdown cierto?

Comment: Correcto, ya que por instinto uno da click al link padre y lo que hace es abrir el contenido del dropdown como es su naturaleza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al dropdown le agregue un id `#dropdown-mensualidades`, el cual le asigno un evento click para posteriormente indicarle un `stopPropagation()` para que no se abra automáticamente, ya con esto puedes darle click y el te redireccionará, aparte si quieres desplegar el dropdown le agregue un evento **hover** para que muestre y oculte los items cuando el menú este arriba de este:

```js
$("#dropdown-mensualidades").on("click", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$('#dropdown-mensualidades').hover(function() {
  $(".dropdown-menu").delay(200).show();
}, function() {
  $(".dropdown-menu").delay(1000).hide(500);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<li id="dropdown-mensualidades" class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a title="Ver Mensualidades" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="mensualidades.php" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="fa fa-money-bill-alt fa-fw"></i>  Mensualidades <span data-toggle="popover" title="Mensualidad Detectada" data-content="Se ha detectado un pago de Mensualidad, pendiente de conformacion." class="badge badge-light"><?php suma_mensualidad(); 
         echo $pendiente_mensualidad; ?></span>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a title="Mensualidades por Aprobar" class="dropdown-item" href="mensualidades.php"><i class="fa fa-money-check fa-fw"></i> Mensualidades por Aprobar</a>
          <a title="Ver Todas las Mensulidades" class="dropdown-item" href="todas_mensualidades.php"><i class="fa fa-list-alt fa-fw"></i> Ver todas las Mensualidades</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo en responder, pero al intentar implementar la sugerencia resulta que el hover al pasar el mouse despliega todo los dropdown-menu intentare analizar tu sugerencia a ver como la puedo implementar en mi código y que quede funcional..! imagino que entra en conflicto con el hover propio del dropdown-menu o con la configuracion que poseo en mi script para auto marcar la web activa que logicamnte esta escuchando directamente los elementos del dropdown-menu..!! tratare de hacerlo solo.. si no lo logro edito la pregunta y deje mas del codigo que poseo..!

Comment: ahh ok entiendo, bueno en el dropdown de mensualidades colocale un id y en el hover llamalo por el id asi no te despliegan todos los dropdowns

Comment: perfecto, cambie de usar l dropdown-menu a usar el ID